# Using Parse.com to load UIWebView from UITableView Cell Selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, parse-platform, nsstring

I have created an "events table", which features the event name, the date and location. Upon clicking each event cell, I am trying to load a specific event URL into a web view. Completely lost.

I have integrated a "prepareForSegue" in the ViewController.m, and have successfully loaded a single url into each table cell that is defined within the code, but I cannot seem to load a string of URLs from Parse.com. The rest of the event table data is loaded fine from Parse.. i'm just struggling with the URL.

Can anybody help?

This is what I have for the individual url load:

```
-(void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.eventWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


self.title = event.name;
[self loadRequestFromString:@"http://www.airleague.co.uk"];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

[self setEventWebView:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

My segue is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEventDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    EventDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
    event.name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    event.eventURL = [object objectForKey:@"eventURL"];

    destViewController.event = event;

}
}


@end
```

Comment: The code shows nothing about how your defining the urls, or retrieving  them from Parse. Please show the relevant code to that

Comment: Hi soulshined. That's what I am stuck with. I don't know how to retrieve from parse.

Comment: How do you have it stored in your Parse backend? What's the column type? String?

Comment: Yes they are stored as a string.

Comment: So you've subclassed something as Event? What is Event?

Comment: l Ugh I don't think I know anymore. :-( I think I've taken on too much too soon! Do you mean in the last part of the segue?

Comment: How about this @JenTye if your comfortable with it. Delete your parse API keys from didFinishLaunching and post the project somewhere I can download and take a look at. I think it's just a communication barrier right now. Not necessarily anything anyone is doing wrong. Then I will update an answer on here

Comment: That would be amazing. I can't find any kind of private message system on here, but would you be happy sending me an email and I will reply with the project download... jennifer.k.tye@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

for:

```
[self loadRequestFromString:NSString];
```

to work, the url should have @"http://" (or any protocol) in the url. 
 
For example it must be "http://google.com" and NOT "google.com"

Does you urls in Parse.com have the protocol in the string?

Comment: I have listed the urls in a string with http://  I'm not sure however how to change my code from a single defined url to the string on parse.com.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to retrieve your objects, which are stored as a string:

So in your viewDidLoad you perform the following query like this:

```
PFQuery *urlQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WebViewURLs"];
urlQuery.cachedPolicy = whateverPolicyYouWant;
[urlQuery selectKeys:@[@"NameOfURLColumn"]];
[urlQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.urlArray = objects;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.urlArray);
        //you'll notice the NSLog logs all attributes to that array, so if you want to narrow it down to a specific column you can do something like this:
        self.urlArray = [objects valueForKey:@"NameOfColumn"];
    }
}];
```

So now you have the objects in an array and you can act accordingly. Your going to have to be more specific with your set up if you want a more specific answer. I'm just guessing at this point since i'm not a mind reader...yet :)

---

**EDIT** after taking a gander from the project you sent to me via email...

A quick synopsis for other users looking for an answer similar:

Ensure your IBOutlet connections are singular and attached to their respective owners.

Additionally the OP wasn't segueing properly, they were allocating a new subclass every time the cell was selected, but wasn't passing any information to the webView View Controller.

It's also worth to point out the OP had subclassed the tableView to Parses `PFQueryTableViewController`

Make sure you properly call your destination view controller and pass information to a properly set property in the Detail VCs header :

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailVC"]) {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

destViewController.eventURL = [object objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
destViewController.eventName = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Detail VC Header

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *eventURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *eventName;
```

Detail VC implementation :

```
//Load the webView in viewDidLoad:
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.eventURL]]];
```

Comment: Okay, so the code above retrieves the string of URLs specific to each event. I'm still at a bit of a loss so I will try and be more specific. 

So the UIWebview I have defined as eventWebView, which I have synthesised in my EventDetailViewController.m, along with the event.h file.

I have defined the IBOutlet in my EventDetailViewController.h as:

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *eventWebView;

In parse core, the column of URLs is called eventURL and type is String.

I am not sure what "Policy" is in your code, and Class Name, what does this refer to?

Comment: @JenTye [policy cache](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-caching/iOS) see link for reference. Class Name is the name of the class you named in Parse.com to hold the url strings. and where `selectKeys:@[@""]];` is put `selectKeys:@[@"eventURL"]];`

Comment: Class Name and Cache Policy now sorted, thank you.

I cannot seem to get rid of an error to do with the urlArray: not found on object of type DetailViewController.

Also, I //'d that part out to eradicate the errors temporarily, and unfortunately nothing loaded on the UIWebview...

Comment: @JenTye yes. Your missing a lot of fundamental basics about segueing information. Unfortunately for me I can't see your project or how it's step up. So I'm just assuming. You should put the query in the main view. And store it in an array. And just guessing here, when you click on a tableView you pass the url from the cell you click to a string property in the detail view.

Comment: In other words this shouldn't be in detail view unless your querying  against parameters. Like. whereKey: equalTo: or something of the sort

Comment: I see, so the PFQUery should  be in the TableViewCOntroller, not the DetailViewController.

Here is my segue:

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEventDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        EventDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
        event.name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
        event.ntURL = [object objectForKey:@"eventURL"];

destViewController.event = event;
        
    }
}


@end

Comment: @JenTye can you please post your segue method in your question so it benefits all people who want to answer. They aren't likely to read through comments to see it. It also is easier on the eyes to read in the question code form. But yes to answer your first question, it sounds like in your circumstance you want it in the main VC. But it's not mandatory it all just depends on the set up. I will update my answer tonight based off your segue method.

Comment: Sorry @soulshined I'm new to stack. Will post it under my question. I wondered why it had gone into an ugly block like that.